# Navigating to detail view on button click in List Row(TableviewCell) in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have List/TableView with Cells. Now each cell contains detail about given Item and some buttons like Edit the Item, Show Detail of Item, Show subview of given Item etc.

Now, for case of showing detail of Item, I have tried to add `NavigationLink`, but now if anyone clicks anywhere on that cell, it moves to detail screen.

I dont want to move to detail screen on clicking anywhere in screen, I want to push detail screen only when someone clicks "Show Detail" button in that cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the `.hidden()` modifier on the `navigationLink` to prevent the list item from capturing it's action
2. Change the `.buttonStyle` from `automatic` to **something else** on the **list item** to prevent it from capturing the button action. (for example `borderless`)

##### Working Demo

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTag: Int?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(1...10, id: \.self) { id in
                HStack {
                    Text("Item \(id: id)")
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button("Show detail") { selectedTag = id }
                    .background(link(id))
                }.buttonStyle(.borderless) ///  ⚠️ on the item! **NOT** on the button!!!
            }
        }
    }
    
    func link(id: Int) -> some View {
        NavigationLink("",
            destination: Text("\(id) Selected"),
            tag: id,
            selection: $selectedTag
        ).hidden()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping... SwiftUI made some difficult things simpler and Simple things difficult.